# Question Highlighting

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

Is it possible to have a similar highlighting on the Questions Tab according to the favorites and ignored tags lists as on the website?

Answer (score 2):

This was added a while back.  You should see your favorite tags highlighted in blue on the question list.

Comment: Sure was! Now how do I favorite tags again? [Oh right](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254523/manage-favorite-tags-in-ios-app) ;)

Comment: @mhlester I saw this when searching `[ios-app] favorite tags`.  So... I'm looking at it. :)

Comment: lol, I'm preaching to the choir

Comment: I added that feature request when testing [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254214/favourite-tags-added-through-tag-summary-dont-sync-to-app) caught me with tags I didn't want