# Please hide questions with tags I chose to ignore and hide (on iOS app)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, ios-app, ignored-tags

I tend to use the Stack Exchange app over the weekends to do a bit of general browsing.  One of the sites is Board & Card Games, on which I've set it up, on the website, to hide `magic-the-gathering` tagged questions.  These still show on the iPad, and given the nature of the site tend to drown out most other questions.

The app already highlights questions tagged with a user's favorite tags.  Could we also have the app hide questions tagged with tags the user has marked for being ignored?

Comment: Not a bug, this feature is simply not supported on the app. [There is already a feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230510/question-highlighting) asking to add such support.

Comment: @Shadow That feature request appears to have been dealt with, at least in part - my favourite tags are highlighted on the app.  Since it seems it's been partially dealt with, and doesn't specifically deal with hiding ignored tags (more just the formatting), I'm inclined to leave this one here?

Comment: Weird... pinged a dev hopefully he'll take a look soon.

Comment: @Shadow Great, thanks

Comment: Are you referring to the main questions listing for a given site?

Comment: @Ben Yes, if I tap the menu button in the top left (on the iPhone version, at least), then tap the site, I see a list of questions.  The questions in this list contain ones that include a hidden tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic limitation here is that as of version 2.2, the API doesn't give the app a way to retrieve a user's favorite/ignored tags.  There is an endpoint in the upcoming version of the API (as of yet unreleased) that will provide this information.

I didn't find a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) post for this, so this is probably a good candidate for being retagged as a feature request.

Comment: ok, I'll retag it.  However, it does highlight questions with my favourite tags on Stack Overflow - is there a different version of the API in place for different sites?

Comment: No, there is only one API for all the sites.  There is a private API with a very small surface area that is just for the feed.

Answer (score 0):

This will be added to some extent in 1.4.3.5.

We will now be dimming out ignored tags in the same manner as the web (`opacity: 0.35`).  Things will also work out so if I'm browsing [swift](/questions/tagged/swift) on SO everything isn't necessarily highlighted (unless a similar tag is highlighted).  Likewise, if I browse [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) everything won't be dimmed.

The only place where we straight-up don't show ignored tags (to my knowledge) is in interesting/home which isn't implemented in the API.

[image: Screenshot showing question list with highlighted and dimmed questions.]

Comment: It's a shame it's not going to match the main question list - even with them greyed out, the volume of questions on some sites I'm simply not interested in will still cause a lot of scrolling.

Comment: Thinking more, surely if you have the information to grey them out, it's not a big step to hiding them entirely?