# Favourite tags added through tag summary don't sync to app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, tag-watching

Had problems with my favourite tags syncing to the app for a while. ([report1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240059/233816), [report2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250996/233816)) Think I've finally figured it out. I add my favourites using the wee star on the tag excerpt pop up.

[image]

Tags favourites added this way don't appear to sync to the app. Only ones added through the side bar do - and push any others at the same time.

Comment: How long did you wait after adding with the star before trying through the side bar? There could be a cashing delay for the push regardless of method used

Comment: @mhlester About 4 months :-)

Comment: So I added a couple tag favorites, saw they didn't update to the app, and removed them. Now all of a sudden they've copied over, even though they were removed on the site. Ug

Comment: @mhlester: I had something similar, but they cleared a couple of hours later, I presume that's cache? Or have yours not cleared?

Comment: No not yet. I could wait a couple months and see if they clear!

Comment: @mhlester haha, fair enough!

Comment: The client-side cache has a 6 minute duration and should be reset if you log out and back in.  Can you try relogging in?

Comment: Hi @Brian - no joy. As in the comments about, I've been waiting for my tag to sync to the app for about 4 months or so now, I'd imagine any cache would have expired!

Comment: I've got it.  If you update your tags from Preferences when editing your profile, you should see the change pretty quickly propagate to your app.  If you use the star, not at all.  I've got a fix going through code review.

Comment: @BrianNickel yup - that's the problem! Great, glad it's finally tracked down!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed for all versions of the app.

There were two caching issues with tag preferences.

The first was simply that we weren't cache breaking when editing tags from a tag summary.  I've added a cache breaker to that code path.

The second was that tag preferences were using ID based cache breaking kind of shoehorned into tag preferences.  When a question/answer/comment get modified, a cache breaker gets set up with the pair `(postType, postId)`.  When a method is called, its cache is retrieved and if any of the items have a broken item ID the cache is discarded.  For tag preferences it was `(TagPreference, userId)` instead.  This worked for cases where there were one or more items to test against, but if you were going from zero to one tag preference, the cache breaking logic wouldn't find any items with that ID and assume the cache was still good.  Now tag preference caching is broken at the method level with the pair `(methodId, userId)` so even zero to one will be invalidated.