# Favorite/Unfavorite tags in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, tag-watching

Could we add Favorite / Unfavorite buttons to the Tag Info page in the iOS app?

> [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be added in 1.4.4.1, shipping in February.

The right nav bar item will let you toggle through normal/favorite/ignored like it does on the web.

[image: Screenshot of fix.]

Comment: I'm running 1.6.1 but don't see any star icon on the Tag Info header. iOS 10. Has it regressed, or how else do I now make a tag a favourite?

Comment: @JohnRees This will be fixed in 1.6.2.3, shipping next week.